# javac adding classpath breaks my local class compilation

Tags: java, import, javac, java-package

When I import a package to my `MyLib` class (which requires `-cp` to javac) I can no longer compile my `MyMain` class.

MyMain.java:

```
class MyMain
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        MyLib.do_stuff ();
    }
}
```

MyLib.java:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;

class MyLib
{
    public static void do_stuff ()
    {
        System.out.println ("Hello.");
    }
}
```

When I `javac MyLib.java` I have do do it like this

```
javac -cp GSON_JAR_PATH MyLib.java
```

That works but if I

```
javac MyMain.java
```

I get

```
./MyLib.java:1: error: package com.google.gson does not exist
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
```

but if I add `-cp` to the compilation command

```
javac -cp GSON_JAR_PATH MyMain.java
```

I get

```
MyMain.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
                MyLib.do_stuff ();
                ^
  symbol:   variable MyLib
  location: class MyMain
```

Comment: Nope. I still get "cannot find symbol MyLib" either with `-cp .,PATH` or `-cp . -cp PATH`.

Comment: That did it, thanks. Want to make an actual answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "-cp path1:path2" - colon separated. (semicolon works on windows) (the parameter to cp is quoted....

```
javac -cp path1:path2 //or ; for windows.
```

Note 1 - setting `-cp` *overrides* any existing CLASSPATH environment or default 
 path setting.

Note 2 - if no CLASSPATH setting then default is '.' - until the -cp overrides that.

So in the posted case - the "." was set for path (either CLASSPATH or default) up until the -cp was used which overrode that default - so it needs to be added back in.